# Capture any embedded map larger than screen

Tags: web-mapping, mapping, embeddable-web-maps

I use the various map portals on the daily basis, like below:

[image]

and the biggest problem is, that my capture is restricted to the screen, being precisely to the area, where the map is embedded, as you can see above.

I found several tools, which are able to capture the maps larger than screen, but unfortunately they work only for Google Maps.

https://superuser.com/questions/145642/how-to-take-a-screenshot-of-a-something-bigger-than-the-screen

https://www.bpwebs.com/print-a-large-google-map-larger-than-the-screen/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22210034/making-screenshot-of-google-map-bigger-than-my-device-screen

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/5734/can-i-extract-a-google-maps-mashup-bitmap-that-is-larger-than-my-screen

I need something which could be able to grab the map content from any existing interactive map (i.e. LEaflet, Openlayers, and so on) with a resolution larger than the screen.
Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

There is one of the options, which works fine for some mapping platforms.
If we have the option of saving our map as the raster file (.png or .tiff), we can on our keyboard simply hold the `Ctrl` button and hit the "`-`" button making our website appearance smaller. In this way, we can gain a larger area for capture.
More details about this option you can find here:

http://www.mkrgeo-blog.com/how-to-capture-any-interactive-map-larger-than-screen-easily/

[image]